# Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in

Tags: php

Quero atribuir objetos a um `array` com `array_push`, porém está dando erro:

> Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in

Minha classe :

```
<?php

//PREPARA UMA RODADA    
class Rodada
{
    $partidas = array();

    //PREENCHE O ARRAY
    public function preencheRodada($partidas, Partida $partida)
    {
        array_push($partidas, $partida);
    }   

    //RETORNA O ARRAY DE PARTIDAS
    public function getRodada()
    {
        return $partidas;
    }
}
```

classe de teste

```
    require_once('../logica/models/Time.php');
require_once('../logica/models/Partida.php');
require_once('../logica/models/Rodada.php');

$time1 = new Time("SANTOS FC");
$time2 = new Time("BARCELONA FC");

$partida1 = new Partida($time1, $time2);
$partida1->setGolsTime1(2);
$partida1->setGolsTime2(3);

$rodada1 = new Rodada();
$rodada1->preencheRodada($partida1);

$partidasDaRodada = $rodada1->getRodada();
```

Comment: É mais fácil usar  `$this->partidas[] = $partida`. É mais rápido que usar a função `array_push` e isso faz a mesma coisa

Comment: Algumas das respostas te serviu, se sim pode aceita-la ???

Answer (score 3):

Mude o seu método `preencheRodada` da classe Rodada

```
//PREENCHE O ARRAY
public function preencheRodada(Partida $partida)
{
    array_push($this->partidas, $partida);
}
```

---

Mude também o seu método `getRodada`

```
//RETORNA O ARRAY DE PARTIDAS
public function getRodada()
{
    return $this->partidas;
}
```

---

**Motivo do Erro:**

O erro acontece, pois quando você chama o método, ele esta esperando 2 argumentos, o primeiro seria o `array` e o segundo a partida

Comment: Cara muito obrigado, funcionou, esqueci desse " $this-> "

Comment: :), escolha como resposta correta, para que possa ajudar outras pessoas que tenham o mesmo problema. abs

Answer (score 2):

O Jeferson já deu uma solução ao problema, mas estou complementando para comentar mais específicamente sobre a causa inicial do problema.

Note na definição do método:

```
public function preencheRodada($partidas, Partida $partida)
```

O primeiro parâmetro é `$partidas`. Isto faz com que a variável de mesmo nome da classe não seja usada, pois ao especificar `$partidas` como parâmetro, este fica com escopo local apenas. Além disso, só faria sentido especificar este parâmetro inicial se ele fosse vir de fora da classe.

A solução mais simples seria definir o método desta forma:

```
public function preencheRodada(Partida $partida)
```